# get date, time and time zone from 2016-06-24T00:00:00.000+05:45

Tags: php, datetime-format

In php, I have a date time format with time zone like : 2016-06-24T00:00:00.000+05:30.

What I want to achieve is :

1. get date time in easily readable any format
2. get time zone

I saw in java, it is gained using SimpleDateFormat(). But,  I could not figure out how it is done. Any body has any idea in PHP?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at PHP's [DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `DateTime` class for time:

```
$date = '2016-06-24T00:00:00.000+05:45';
$dt = new DateTime($date);
var_dump( $dt->getTimezone() );
var_dump( $dt->format("d.m.Y H:i") );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: `var_dump( $dt->getTimeZone()->getName());` did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

Use strtotime() function to covert string into UNIX time stamp. Then use date() function to display date/time in desired format. Date/Time formats can be found here http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
echo date('F Y h:i:s A', strtotime('2016-06-24T00:00:00.000+05:30'));
```